# Connecting Bluetooth module to arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I have a RN 41 (Roving networks) bluetooth module, have no breakout board, want to connect it to Arduino duemilanove, can anyone please help with the circuit diagram and the components required to connect module to arduino

Comment: What do you want that's not on the typical application circuit of page 4 of the datasheet? (see http://www.rovingnetworks.com/documents/RN-41.pdf )

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a [prototype shield](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=7914) with the module mounted "dead bug" style (upside down - in this case with the RF cover on the prototype grid). Use hot glue or double sided tape to secure it. Then, solder wires from the Bluetooth module pads to the Arduino shield pins.

Note that you can mount the module at the end, to give the required RF keepout clearance the datasheet calls out.